# Sublime Text 2: How to open new sublime text window in different workspace on Ubuntu?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Ubuntu, when I'm working with multiple workspaces, if I open sublime-text via terminal or the search bar, it doesn't open a new window.

Instead it points me back to the sublime-text window in some other workspace. This is counterintuitive since the point of workspaces is to have separate work pieces.

Is there any way to  fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
subl -n
```

to open a new sublime window.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal go to the project folder and do:

```
subl /
```

This will open your previous project as well as the project you want to open.